# Azure BLOB possible bug - Random wrong file

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

So, I know it is kinda crazy to report bug at this point in Azure life cycle, but I'm out of options. Here we go.

We have a service that you can upload files and a client that download then. That BLOB is stuffed with about 27 GB of data.

In a few occasions our users reported that some files were coming wrong, so we checked our MVC route to see if was anything wrong and found nothing.

So we created a simple console that loop the download:

```
public static void Main()
{

    var firstHash = string.Empty;
    var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss-ffff");

            var destination = @"C:\Users\Israel\Downloads\RO65\BLOB - RO65 -" + date + ".rfa";
            client.DownloadFile("http://myboxfree.blob.core.windows.net/public/91fe9d90-71ce-4036-b711-a5300159abfa.rfa", destination);

            string hash = string.Empty;
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                using (var stream = File.OpenRead(destination))
                {
                    hash = Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(stream));
                }
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstHash))
                firstHash = hash;

            if (hash != firstHash) hash += " ---------------------------------------------";
            Console.WriteLine("i: " + i.ToString() + " = " + hash);
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

So here is the result - every now and then it downloads the wrong file:

[image]

The first 1000 downloads were OK, the right file. Out of the blue the BLOB returns a different file, and then goes back to normal.

The only relation I found between the files are the extension and the file size in bytes. The hash is (of course) different.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd say the only people who can give any actual answers to this would be Azure support. You have what appears to be a well documented bug with a method to reproduce it. Log it (if you haven't already!) and let us know how it goes!

Comment: Trying to repro now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried to rerun your sample code and wasn't able to repro.

Questions:

- For the two different versions of the files you are seeing downloaded have you compared the contents of the two files? I think you said it was two completely different blobs being retrieved - however I wanted to verify that. How large is the delta between the two files?
- Are you using RA-GRS and the client libraries read from secondary retry condition - meaning a network glitch could result in the read coming from the secondary region?

Suggestions:

- Can you track the etag of the retrieved files. This allows you to check if the blob has changed since you first started reading it?
- The Storage Service does enable you to explicitly validate the integrity of your objects to check to see if they have been modified in transit - potentially due to network issues etc. See [Azure Storage Md5 Overview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/02/18/windows-azure-blob-md5-overview.aspx) for more information. The simplest way however might just be to use https as these validations are already built into https.
- Can you also try to repro using https and let me know if that helps?

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason. Seems like the HTTPS solved everything instantly! But I'll check the all the things you mentioned to make sure this doesn't happens again.